# How to disable lighttpd access log?

Tags: linux, lighttpd

I'm using lighttpd and access.log is increasing too fast.

Is there a good way to disable access log?

At the lighttpd.conf seems that is possible to disable "mod_accesslog" in the "server.modules", but the comment advices to don't do.

lighttpd 1.4.35

Comment: I think this community would be better for this question: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Yes, I thought this, but stackoverflow returned 3,595 results against 1,893 of serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

If you have neither `accesslog.filename = "..."` or `accesslog.use-syslog = "enable"` in your lighttpd.conf, then there will be no access logging.  If you want to disable access logging, comment these lines out of your lighttpd.conf and restart the lighttpd server to pick up the changes.